# Wrong HttpWebRequest Accept-Range value in C#

Tags: c#, http-headers, httpwebrequest

I want to know if a URL source supports ranged requests.

To get it I am using this method:

```
bool DoesSupportsRange(string url)
{
   HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
   HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
   return resp.Headers.AllKeys
                    .Select((v, i) => new
                    {
                        HeaderName = v,
                        HeaderValue = resp.Headers[i]
                    })
                    .Any(k => k.HeaderName == "Accept-Ranges" && k.HeaderValue == "bytes");
}
```

It returns `True` for this [sample.rar](https://dev-files.blender.org/file/data/fbesofb22svautbktglp/PHID-FILE-onmshh3l6jhqdeq3ctdz/sample.rar) file. But in fact, `WebRequest.AddRange(0,1)` request returns **76180 bytes** instead **2 bytes**. So the value must be `False` for it.

I want to ask what is the exact method to get the correct information for this header?

Comment: I dont think your code is at fault, its the server serving this file, I've tried curl and Postman and they give similar results. Try any other resource that you expect to support ranges, I've tried one from [this page](https://www.cyberciti.biz/cloud-computing/http-status-code-206-commad-line-test/) for example

Comment: I faced this problem only once with this url. The function gives correct results with other range supported or not urls. This is an issue I don't understand why it happens.

Comment: My guess would be that server you are testing is just either sending you "Accept-Ranges" by mistake or have a bug in handling "Ranges" from client, there's nothing you can do about it Im afraid

Comment: It may be. However servers are complex machines and they could have some exceptions. Possible.